How should I update the functions after changing the table columns?
Let's assume I have a table with 2 columns: column1 and column2.
Now, I create a function based on the table as follows:
CREATE OR ALTER Function [dbo].[Fn_Test] ()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
        SELECT *
        FROM Table1

If later I add a third column to the table or remove one of the columns, my function does not get updated, and I have to alter my function again. How can I update all functions at once, or is there a way for the functions related to that table to be updated after changes are made to the table?

You shouldn't be using SELECT * in your definitions; you should be specific in the columns you want. SELECT * does not mean "return all the columns in the object(s) in the FROM at the time of execution" when used in objects like functions and views.

Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 but you need to do it manually

As for the need to update your functions, I would question if those functions need to be updated. If you need to return every column in your objects in all your functions, it sounds like maybe you shouldn't be using functions for those processes.

The answer you're looking for is WITH SCHEMABINDING.

@Dai - that doesn't do anything to automatically make new added columns available or alert the user that they need to update the projected column list https://dbfiddle.uk/534luyUc

@MartinSmith Ah yes, I misunderstood the OP.

RE the question here I don't see anything inherently wrong with trying to use * here. e.g. in the case that the desired semantics for the view/ inline function are to return some horizontal partition of all columns. As these are inline the query optimiser should be able to only select the final needed columns from the base object in queries referencing Fn_Test. the only problem is SQL Server not automatically detecting these changes and updating its column metadata as needed. So you need to use sp_refreshsqlmodule if doing so. SSDT deployments will probably detect this and do it for you.


If later we add a third column to the table or remove one of the columns, my function does not get updated, and I have to alter my function again.

Yup.

How can I update all functions at once, or is there a way for the functions related to that table to be updated after changes are made to the table?

You'll need to bring your own tooling for code-generation, ideally within an SSDT (*.sqlproj) project, because things like that should be under source-control, and relatedly: no-one should be making any ad-hoc edits to database objects (like procedures, functions, views, etc) in a production/live database, and finally because by using SSDT (or similar tooling like SQLAlchemy) means you can use things like T4 to automatically generate the  SELECT <column-list> (for views/functions/procdures) directly from your CREATE TABLE definitions.
...but none of this is automatic nor managed for you by MSSQL Server. When you use SSDT your changes get applied during a separate Publish process or via the Schema Compare feature.

In your case, where you want a FUNCTION to be kept in-sync with a TABLE, then you'd want something like this:
MyFunction.sql.tt (this is a T4 Template)
In your T4 Template's <#+ (template class defintiion block) you'd use EnvDTE and/or SqlCodeAnalysisRule to get your CREATE TABLE definitions and re-generate the function definition:
Here's an article from a while ago, but I think is still relevant, which uses EnvDTE to get CREATE TABLE definitions, which I've used as the basis for the T4 template below. See also this QA.
Note: I haven't updated the Visual Studio COM interop references from the 2014 article, so they'll be out-of-date for VS2022 today, but it's trivial to fix that and so is left-up as an exercise for the reader:
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostspecific="true" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE80" #>
<#@ assembly name="VSLangProj" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE80" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".sql" #>
<#
    using TSqlModel model = this.CreateTSqlModel();

    TSqlTable myTable = RequireTable( model, "MyTable" );
 
#>

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction() RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN

SELECT
<#    foreach( Column c in myTable.Columns ) { /* See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model.column?view=sql-dacfx-162 */ #>
    t.<#= c.Name #>,
<#    } // foreach Column #>
FROM
    dbo.MyTable;

END;

<#+
 
    public TSqlModel CreateTSqlModel()
    {
        IServiceProvider hostServiceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
        DTE              dte                 = (DTE)hostServiceProvider.GetService( typeof(DTE) );

        TSqlModel model = new TSqlModel(SqlServerVersion.Sql110, new TSqlModelOptions { });

        IReadOnlyList<ProjectItem> tableItems = dte.Solution.Cast<Project>()
            .SelectMany( p => p.ProjectItems )
            .Where( i => i.Name.EndsWith( ".sql", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) )
            .Where( i => i.FileCount == 1 && i.FileNames[0].Contains( "Tables" ) ) )
            .ToList();

        foreach( ProjectItem tableItem in tableItems )
        {
            String sqlText = File.ReadAllText( tableItem.FileNames[0] );
            if( sqlText.Contains( "CREATE TABLE" ) )
            {
                model.AddObjects( sqlText );
            }
        }

        return model;
    }

    public static TSqlTable RequireTable( TSqlModel model, String tableName )
    {
        return model.GetObjects<TSqlTable>( DacQueryScopes.All, ModelSchema.Table )
            .Cast<TSqlTable>()
            .Where( t => t.Name == tableName )
            .Single();
    }

#>

